# Show that for any graph $G$ there is an ordering of the vertices for which the greedy algorithm requires $χ(G)$ colors.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm learning about the greedy algorithm, but this question is to general for me to grasp (I ave no idea where to begin). Could someone please explain how I solve the problem?

Show that for any graph $G$ there is an ordering of the vertices for which the greedy algorithm requires $χ(G)$ colors.

Answer (score 4):

Start with a coloring with $\chi(G)$ colors.  Put all the vertices in color class $1$ at the start of the ordering.  The greedy algorithm with color them all with color $1$.  Put the vertices in color class $2$ next in the ordering.  The greedy algorithm will color them all with color $1$ or $2$.  It will not color them all with color $1$ though.  (Why not?)  Continue in this fashion.